# How do I rename my weapons?

Tags: payday-2

I've seen some screenshots where the person renamed their gun.

How do I rename mines? The only options are modify, move, sell, preview.  No option to rename, nothing in options either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the inventory screen, select the weapon you want renamed, then click on its default name at the right panel. This will allow you to type in a custom weapon name.

[image]

Note that [you can only rename weapons with a mouse and keyboard on the PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228966/4797). You can not rename weapons on consoles (with a controller).

Comment: Wow, had no idea, thank you.  I was skeptical at first since before someone told me you could rename but I looked all over for an option and never saw one

Comment: Can they be renamed as much as we want, or is it a one-time only kinda function? And does it cost anything to do?

Comment: @Sharain Weapons can be renamed as many times as you want. It does not cost anything.