# How do I change my weapon's name on Payday 2 for PS4?

Tags: ps4, payday-2

I know that you can change it on PC, but I don't know how to do it on PS4.

Comment: Related: [How do I rename my weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/190755/4797)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change weapon names with any controller enabled.

This is only available on the PC with keyboard and mouse. Even on the PC, if you are playing with a controller, this is not possible.